# TCP Read Hangs on Reading Partial Content Data (HTTP Response code 206)

Tags: sockets, http, https, tcp

I am doing tcp read using the socket.
The contents are getting read but as the last chunk of bytes are read and again it tries for reading again and gets the error as EAGAIN. This is only happening with partial content(HTTP response 206). As per the normal behaviour it should have returned EOF, so that sockets could been closed and further processing could have been done.

So, is it normal behaviour for 206 and I have to do handling when whole content is read? Or how do I handle this??

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special with response code 206. It is send as a response to a request for some range of bytes.

> As per the normal behaviour it should have returned EOF, ...

It is perfectly fine that the server is keeping the connection open after the response is sent as long as the client signaled that it is fine with that, i.e. by using an explicit `Connection: keep-alive` or implicitly by using `HTTP/1.1` with no explicit `Connection: close`.